# Shouldn't the "grids" tag be split into, say "grid-typesetting" and "grids"?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tagging

I've just [asked a question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/49317/how-to-do-grid-typesetting-with-amsmath) and decided to tag it "grid-typesetting", having a vague feeling that the "grids" tag is not a best one here.  Soon lockstep edited it and changed "grid-typesetting" into "grids".  While I'm fine with this, I decided to check whether my feeling was right, and I think yes: the "grids" tag is used both for graphical things (usually with tikz) connected e.g. with different coordinate systems *and* for grid typesetting.

There's also an "ltxgrid" tag, but this is too narrow - `ltxgrid` is probably not the only way to do grid typesetting in LaTeX, and there's ConTeXt, too.

So: what do you think?  Is a "grid-typesetting" tag needed?  (If yes, I could look through the questions tagged "grids" - there are not too many of them - and retag them accordingly.)

Comment: I couldn't resist to remove the [meta-tag:retagging] tag. ;-)

Comment: @lockstep: I wanted to put only ";)" in the comment, seemingly this is impossible;).

Comment: Any chance of accepting my answer?

Comment: @lockstep: you're welcome, and sorry for the delay.  I usually prefer to wait with accepting, hoping for more and/or better answers - maybe too long...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

On the one hand, grid typesetting *does* involve aligning things to a coordinate system (here: determined by `\baselineskip`); on the other hand, it is a subject that calls for a distinct kind of expertise than "programming" diagrams with, say, TikZ. Based on the latter, I'm leaning towards a separate [grid-typesetting](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grid-typesetting) tag.

EDIT: ienissei and I retagged 11 questions to [grid-typesetting](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grid-typesetting); one question now features both [grid-typesetting](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grid-typesetting) and [grids](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grids).

Comment: Please add the [{grid-typesetting}](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grid-typesetting) tag.  I am very interested in that, and not at all interested in TikZ related problems at the moment.